# Is there a way to see if gradle cache has been changed

Tags: caching, gradle, dependencies

Am trying to find a way to know if the cache dependency of gradle has been modified during a build for exemple.

As far as I can tell, the only way to see a change is to look at the size of the directory, but I am not sure if it's very efficient.

Comment: I don't know about any such mechanism, also I can't find any such thing in gradle's public API.

Comment: there is no public api for that in gradle at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gradle's cache in a performance implementation detail. There is no easy way to determine of the cache has been modified.**